# Showing $2 Q = Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finitely-generated

I want to show these two statements:

1- Show that $2 \mathbb Q = \mathbb Q.$

2-Show that $\mathbb Q$ is not a finitely generated $A$ module.

For the first statement I do not know how to show it, so if someone can help me I would appreciate this.

For the second statement I am guessing that the following is the solution:

Assume that $\mathbb Q = (\frac{a}{b})$ i.e., it is finitely generated , then $q = m \frac{a}{b}$ for some integer $m.$ But then I do not know what to do. Could anyone help me in proving this also please?

Comment: For the first, handle it as any other set equality. Show $2 \mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq 2 \mathbb{Q}$. (If $x \in 2 \mathbb{Q}$ then $x = 2 a/b$ for appropriate $a,b$; is this rational? If $y \in \mathbb{Q}$ then $y = p/q$ for appropriate $p,q$; can you write this as double an appropriate rational?)

Comment: What is $A$ in $A$-module? Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Comment: $y = 2 \frac {p}{2q}$ right @PrincessEev

Comment: @KevinS let me check

Comment: @KevinS I think you are correct

Comment: For $y$, you are correct.

Comment: Finitely generated here would mean $\mathbb{Q} = \langle q_1,...,q_n\rangle_{+,\cdot}$ for some elements $q_i\in \mathbb{Q}$, with $\langle\rangle_{+\cdot}$ denoting iteration through $\mathbb{Z}$-linear combinations. We want to show that no such finite set exists that generates it.

Comment: My method of proving this would be to construct an element using the $q_i$'s that is in $\mathbb{Q}$ but is not in the $\mathbb{Z}$-Span. Try product of all of them say.

Comment: How about taking the element $\frac {1}{2} \frac {a}{m}$ this element is in $\mathbb Q$ then $\frac{1}{2} \frac{a}{m} = m \frac {a}{b}$ but $m$ here is not in $\mathbb Z$ hence a contradiction @KevinS  does this works?

Comment: If $\frac{a}{2m} = \frac{ma}{b}$ then $b = 2m^2$. We assume at the outset that $m$ is an integer, so this $b$ you are introducing is defined by it. No contradiction here. What would this prove even with the contradiction?

Comment: Assume towards contradiction that  $\mathbb Q$ is finitely generated as $\mathbb Z$ module, i.e., $$\mathbb Q = (\frac {a}{b}) = \{m \, \frac {a}{b} \, | m \in \mathbb Z \, , \, \text{gcd (a,b)} = 1\}$$

Now, consider the element $\frac{1}{2} \frac {a}{b},$ this element is in $\mathbb Q$ then $\frac{1}{2} \frac {a}{b} = m \frac {a}{b}$ therefore $m = \frac{1}{2}$ which is a contradiction as $m$ should be in $\mathbb Z.$ @KevinS   ..... this is what I meant sorry

Comment: Okay so here, you've shown that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not generated by any single element. The idea is the same for the general case

Comment: Ok, so it is not cyclic .... but you mean this is not the correct proof ..... right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(1)$ was already handled in the comments...

$(2)$ $\underline{Claim:}$ $\mathbb{Q}$ is an **infinitely-generated** $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
$\underline{Proof:}$ Suppose $\mathbb{Q}$ has a finite generating set, $\{q_1,...,q_n\}\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$. Note that each $q_i = \frac{r_i}{s_i}$ for $r_i,s_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. We have:
$$Span_{\mathbb{Z}}\bigg\{\frac{1}{s_1},...,\frac{1}{s_n}\bigg\} \supseteq Span_{\mathbb{Z}}\bigg\{q_1,...,q_n\bigg\},$$
so without loss of generality, assume the spanning set is of the form on the LHS. Furthermore, suppose this set is *linearly independent*. Now, consider the element:
$$x:= \frac{1}{s_1\cdot ... \cdot s_n}.$$
Clearly $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, but if $x\in Span_{\mathbb{Z}}\bigg\{\frac{1}{s_1},...,\frac{1}{s_n}\bigg\}$ then $\exists \lambda_i\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that:
$$\frac{1}{s_1\cdot ... \cdot s_n} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\frac{1}{s_i}.$$
Clearing the denominator, subtracting the one over, and noting $1 = \frac{s_j}{s_j}$ we get:
$$\implies \sum\limits_{i\neq j = 1}^n\lambda_i\cdot (s_1\cdot ...\cdot s_n)\cdot\frac{1}{s_i} + (\lambda_j\cdot(s_1\cdot ...\cdot s_n)- s_j)\cdot\frac{1}{s_j} = 0$$
Rewriting with new coefficients:
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\mu_i\cdot \frac{1}{s_j} = 0$$
$\implies \forall i:\text{ }\mu_i = 0$ (by linear independence of $\frac{1}{s_i}$'s). This in turn yields:
$$\forall i\neq j:\text{ }\lambda_i\cdot (s_1\cdot...\cdot s_n) = 0$$
and
$$\lambda_j\cdot (s_1\cdot ... \cdot s_n) = s_j.$$
Continuing:
$$\implies \forall i\neq j: \lambda_i = 0\text{ }\text{ (integral domain property of integers)}$$
and
$$\lambda_j = \frac{1}{(s_1\cdot ...\cdot \widehat{s_j}\cdot... \cdot s_n)}\in \mathbb{Q}\backslash \mathbb{Z}$$
and thus we've reached our first contradiction. 
We conclude that $x\in \mathbb{Q}\backslash Span_{\mathbb{Z}}\bigg\{q_1,...,q_n\bigg\}$. So that for the outer contradiction, we have that $\{q_1,...q_n\}$ can't generate all of $\mathbb{Q}$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: but what about my argument for this in the comments?

Comment: Do you mean for the other contradiction in your line before last?

Comment: Also, I did not quite well understand the contradiction(s) that you get, could you please state them in words not using mathematics?

Comment: This could probably be written better, the first one shows anti-containment, the other uses this to contradict the hypothesis. So its like a proof within a proof that uses the same argument form.

Comment: If $\{q_1,q_2\}$ is L.D. then say $q_2\in \langle q_1\rangle $. Hence $\langle q_1\rangle \supseteq \langle q_1,q_2\rangle$. So $x\notin \langle q_1\rangle$ implies $x\notin \langle q_1,q_2\rangle$. That's what I was trying to say

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez so I was able to prove that $Q$ is not cyclic .... can you please show me how can I show that it is not finitely generated from this? maybe in a separate answer or so